# Changing the center point of Group in JavaFX for RotateTransition

Tags: javafx

I can't get the code to work properly. Setting the pivot point's coordinates don't change the center of rotation. My Group still rotates around the center of a Group. Sorry for bad english. Thanks for helping.

```
public class MetronomePathTransitionMain extends Application {

    Ellipse ellipse;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ellipse = new Ellipse(100, 50, 4, 8);
        ellipse.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        ellipse.setRotate(-15);

        Line line = new Line(0, 0, 200, 350);
        line.startXProperty().bind(ellipse.centerXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(ellipse.centerYProperty());

        Group group = new Group(ellipse,line);
        Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
        rotate.setPivotX(200);
        rotate.setPivotY(350);
        group.getTransforms().add(rotate);

        RotateTransition anim = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), group);
        anim.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        anim.setAutoReverse(true);
        anim.setByAngle(30);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        anim.playFromStart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rotate Transform doesn't have an effect in a RotateTransition. You could use a [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) instead.

jewelsea has a great [RotationTransformExample.java example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1475424) on his gist. It should give you an idea how to do it.